# Error in executing command tar -xjf

Tags: shell

While executing command in shell script like as follows i am getting an error please help

```
tar -xjf $tarfile
```

error is :

```
tar: option requires an argument -- f
```

Comment: Maybe $tarfile is empty.

Comment: NO tar file is not empty. I am executing this statement in a shell script

Comment: Are you sure you variable is not empty? Try to add `set -x` in the beginning of your script and run it again. And look carefully in output.

Comment: yes it is a size of 59959 i tried set -x at the beginning but it is also not working giving same error. I am doing coding for jenkins job

Comment: I am sure that the tar file contains something, what I mean is that the $tarfile variable contains nothing.

Comment: no it is retriving file from a list of files

Comment: @LakshmiHayagreevan Please post here the full script and the output after test run with `set -x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then the variable $tarfile is obiviously empty. Argument `f` requires a filename or a hyphen to denote stdin allowing for piping of data to tar. The `j` argument expects to find the tarfile compressed in bzip2 format.

In your script you would have to do something similar:

```
tarfile=/path/to/file.tar.bz2
tar -xjf $tarfile
```

or an example of piping:

```
ssh user@remotehost cat /path/to/file.tar.bz2|tar -xjf -
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the $tarfile variable is empty.